# NSEntityDescription works fine but Analyzer says value never read

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, nsentitydescription

I'm puzzled by a remark from Xcode' analyzer. I've searched Stack about it but didn't really find a similar situation. I have a CoreData/SQLite app where the user select a record in a table, gets all the atributes for the entity. then, based on conditions, will do things.

"ordersController" is the NSArrayController for the data.
"Order" is the involved entity.
"objectAtIndex:0" is the selected record in the table.

Here is the code:

```
NSArray* selectedObjects = [ordersController selectedObjects];
NSEntityDescription *entityOrder = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Order" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
entityOrder = [selectedObjects objectAtIndex:0];
if ([entityOrder valueForKey: bla_bla_bla... { do_something }
```

The app compiles fine, no crash, no warning and correctly handles the data as intended. However when I start the Analyze tool of Xcode, it points at this line, saying "Value stored to 'entityOrder' during its initialization is never read."

```
NSEntityDescription *entityOrder = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Order" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
```

How can it be not read when it is actually manipulated and the variable is correctly modified by the app? How should I improve my code? Thansk for your help.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the `entityOrder = ...` line is essential? As the compiler states this line does essentially nothing as you fetch a description but in the next line already overwrite the value stored in `entityOrder`. You could try skipping the line altogether and going for `NSEntityDescription *entityOrder = [selectedObjects objectAtIndex:0];` and it should produce the same results. If not, the `entityForName` call would have some unprecendented side-effects that should not be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Immediately after the line

```
NSEntityDescription *entityOrder = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Order" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
```

you then reassign it to the contents of first object of `selectedObjects` with

```
entityOrder = [selectedObjects objectAtIndex:0];
```

The Xcode analyzer is letting you know that the first assignment is superfluous, or you are assigning the results of `[selectedObjects objectAtIndex:0]` to the wrong variable in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It was my wrong understanding of how to use NSEntity Description with a CoreData entity.